# Number of real roots of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Let $P\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ be a polynomial such that $(P, P') = 1$. Suppose that we want to calculate the number of real roots of $P$ in the interval $[a, b]$ (to simplify, let us assume that $P(a), P(b) \ne 0$). An answer to this question is given by Sturm's theorem: if we consider the sequence of polynomials

\begin{align*}
P_0(x) &= P(x), \\\
P_1(x) &= P'(x), \\\
P_{k + 1}(x) &= -P_{k - 1}(x) \mod P_k(x), \\\
&\ \ \vdots \\\
0 &= -P_{m - 1}(x) \mod P_m(x).
\end{align*}

Then answer is $W(b) - W(a)$ where $W(c)$ is the number of sign changes (after omitting zeroes) in the sequence the $P_0(c), P_1(c), \ldots , P_m(c)$.

But there is another way to calculate the number of real roots of $P$ in the interval $[a, b]$:

If we consider the function $G(z) = \frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}$ as a function of the complex variable $z$ and integrate it over the rectangle with vertices $b\pm \varepsilon i,a\pm \varepsilon i$ for small enough $\varepsilon$, then the result will be the number of roots of $P$ in $[a, b]$ multiplied by $2\pi i$.

> **Question.** Is there any connection between these two methods or any way to prove Sturm's theorem using complex analysis tools?

It seems possible because in Sturm's theorem we in fact write $G(x)$ as a "continued fraction". If $$Q_k(x) = \frac{P_{k - 1}(x) + P_{k + 1}(x)}{P_k(x)}$$ then

$$\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)} = \frac{1}{Q_1(x) - \frac{1}{Q_2(x)-\frac{1}{\ddots - \frac{1}{Q_{m}(x)}}}}.$$

Comment: How does the method choose $\epsilon$ so it is small enough?

Comment: @CraigFeinstein there should be no zeroes of the form $c+ti$, where $c\in [a,b]$, $0<|t|\leqslant \varepsilon$.

Comment: observation: we may start Euclid's algorithm for any pair of polynomials $P,Q$, not necessary for $P$ and $P'$, and calculate $W(a)-W(b)$, this is an integer. While the integral of a rational function $\frac1{2\pi i} \int Q/P$ over this circuit is generically not an integer. Thus proving that the integral equals $W(a)-W(b)$ we must use somehow that these polynomials are $P$ and $P'$.